# Aggregation of Site usage analytics of Team Sites office 365/SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How to get an overview of all sub sites in a site collection, not only the root site collection? Or How can we get site usage analytics for aggregate information including all sub sites /team sites in a site collection?

Or any other OOTB for getting site usage analytics in Power bi like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[The SharePoint site usage report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/sharepoint-site-usage?view=o365-worldwide#how-to-get-to-the-sharepoint-site-usage-report)** under Microsoft 365 admin center> Reports> Usage will not show subsite url.

As a workaround, we could [**run an audit log search**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#step-1-run-an-audit-log-search) to show all activities in SharePoint Online site, fill in the wildcard character (*) in the search box after the URL to return all entries of the site(including subsites):

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Juli_MSFt, This is worked but there's any option to generate the same in POWER BI